# Angular FormBuilder is undefined in unit tests

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have the following component:

.ts:

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {IValueAndCurrency} from '@model/IValueAndCurrency';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-top-up-amount-change-dialog',
  templateUrl: './top-up-amount-change-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-up-amount-change-dialog.component.scss'],
})
export class TopUpAmountChangeDialogComponent {
  topupAmountFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    topupAmount: [this.data.topupAmount, {
      validators: [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.min(0),
      ]
    }],
  })

  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TopUpAmountChangeDialogComponent>,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)
    public data: {
      topupAmount: IValueAndCurrency;
      possibleAmounts: IValueAndCurrency[];
    },
  ) {
  }

}
```

Unit test:

```
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {TopUpAmountChangeDialogComponent} from './top-up-amount-change-dialog.component';
import {FormBuilder, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {MATERIAL_MODULES} from 'src/app/strong textapp.consts';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {APP_CONFIG} from "../../../../../../../appConfig.injectortoken";
import {TestAppConfigJson} from "../../../../../../app.component.spec";
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import {IValueAndCurrency} from "../../../../../../common/models/IValueAndCurrency";
import {Currency} from "../../../../../../common/models/enums/currency.enum";

fdescribe('TopUpAmountChangeDialogComponent', () => {
  let component: TopUpAmountChangeDialogComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TopUpAmountChangeDialogComponent>;
  const matRefSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('matRefSpy', ['close']);
  const dialogData: { topupAmount: IValueAndCurrency, possibleAmounts: IValueAndCurrency[] } = {
    topupAmount: {
      value: 10,
      currencyCode: Currency.EUR
    },
    possibleAmounts: [
      {
        value: 0,
        currencyCode: Currency.EUR
      },
      {
        value: 0,
        currencyCode: Currency.USD
      }
    ]
  };

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MATERIAL_MODULES,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
      ],
      declarations: [TopUpAmountChangeDialogComponent],
      providers: [
        FormBuilder,
        {provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: TestAppConfigJson},
        {provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: matRefSpy},
        {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: dialogData},
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TopUpAmountChangeDialogComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.data = dialogData;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

If I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
hrome 110.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) TopUpAmountChangeDialogComponent should create FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'group')
            at new TopUpAmountChangeDialogComponent (src/app/modules/.../top-up-amount-change-dialog/top-up-amount-change-dialog.component.ts:12:34)
```

If I move the formControl initialization to the constructor, it works properly. But I don't want to do that: that case I would have to declare my form as an untyped `FormGroup<any>` and therefore I would loose the type safety this provides ([more about this  here, "Avoid This Common Typed Forms Pitfall"](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-typed-forms/).

**Edit:** A correction: I could keep the type information with moving the initialization to the `constructor` or to `ngOnInit`, however, for that I would need to explicitly describe the interface which I feel like is a code duplication: the `formBuilder` could get the type implicitly. So you either do the solution I posted below, or follow this recommendation and add the type information manually.

Comment: Moving it in the constructor does not mean you would have to change the typings of your form. The "clean" way would be to move the initialization into the constructor, or, even better, to `ngOnInit`.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner I see your point, but moving it to NgOnInit or to the Constructor would need me giving explicit typings for the declaration, which I would like to avoid (a simple `topupAmountFormGroup: FormGroup` would result in an `any` type, so I would have to add a new Interface instead, with a lot of boilerplate code) - my solution below allows you to declare and implicitly give the type information at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to not to use the injected `FormBuilder` instance, but in fact, create a new one:

```
export class TopUpAmountChangeDialogComponent {
  topupAmountFormGroup = new FormBuilder().group({
    topupAmount: [this.data.topupAmount, {
      validators: [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.min(0),
      ]
    }],
  })
...
```

It is only implicitly described in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#formbuilder-and-nonnullableformbuilder) and I thought that it should be more clear that in this case we should do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Angular inject function:

```
private fb = inject(FormBuilder);
topupAmountFormGroup = this.fb.group...
```